# Return value in nested arrays in Google Tag Manager

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-tag-manager

My dataLayer currently looks like this:

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: "someEvent",
  hs-form-guid: "someHubspotId",
  email: {
    submittedEmail@domain.com: { //This array is named after the real submitted email
      success: true,
      email: "submittedEmail@domain.com",
      emailShouldResubscribe: false,
      emailFree: false,
      emailSuggestion: null
    }
  }
})
```

I want to return the email value but I'm struggling with the nested array because I cannot return it by name because its name changes every time.

I've created a dataLayer variable 'email.0.email' named Email but is always 'undefined'. Also tried with 'email[0].email' or 'email.[0].email' with no luck.

Also created a second custom JS variable 'function () { return {{Email}}[0]}' but returns undefined too.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I've created an 'email' variable and got this much:
`{submittedEmail@domain.com:{success: true, email: "submittedEmail@domain.com",emailShouldResubscribe: false,emailFree: false,emailSuggestion: null}}`. Still can't seem to extract the email from it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `Custom JavaScript Variable` and here is the code

```
function(){
  var emailDlv = {{DLV-email}};
  var keys = Object.keys(emailDlv)[0];
  return emailDlv[keys]
}
```

Here is the variable in GTM preview

[image]

Comment: I couldn't make your script work, I don't know why, but I did manage to modify the [Hubspot Form Listener tag](https://community.hubspot.com/t5/Marketing-Integrations/HubSpot-Forms-and-Google-Analytics-Events/m-p/320381), and added your Object.keys approach and it works! I'm able to capture the email address and send it to Google Ads on form submission.
Specifically I added a single line: `'email': Object.keys(hubspot._emailValidationAndResubCache)[0]`
I'ld upvote you but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Many thanks, @Darrellwan.

Comment: Full script: `<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if(event.data.type === 'hsFormCallback' && event.data.eventName === 'onFormSubmitted') {
      window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'hubspot-form-success',
        'hs-form-guid': event.data.id,
        'email': Object.keys(hubspot._emailValidationAndResubCache)[0]
      });
    }
  });
</script>`